# Fail to read binary file (from SD card) in Apache cordova for Android App

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am creating an Apache Cordova app to load a binary image stored in the SD card and get the byte array for further processing.

I tried to use following plugins:

- com.megster.cordova.FileChooser (To pick the file and return the file 
   path).
- cordova-plugin-file (To read the file from the file system).

Code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = (function () {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(xhr.response);});
xhr.send();
```

I have used the following code to read the file once the 'url' path is returned from the filechooser plugin.

When we use 'reader.readAsArrayBuffer' with url directly it is saying that it is not of type 'blob'. Later we used  'XMLHttpRequest' to read as 'arraybuffer' and pass then it is loading the JPEG image properly but fails to read my binary file. Please let us know where we went wrong in reading the file.

Comment: I searched the `com.megster.cordova.FileChooser` plugin, but I didn't found an official place for it. Could you please offer a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: It is found in "https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser".

Answer (score 1):

The url returned from [fileChooser plugin](https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser) is a [ContentURL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html), which can not be applied to `FileReader` directly. The correct step is like below:

1. Once you got the url returned from `fileChooser`, call `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI` from File plugin you have added like below:

   ```
   window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(url, function (entry) {
       readFile(entry);
   }, function (failmsg) {
       //handle fail
   }).
   ```
2. Read the file using the `FileEntry` you got:

   ```
   function readFile(fileEntry) {
       fileEntry.file(function (file) {
           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onloadend = function () {
               console.log("Successful file read: " + this.result);
               displayFileData(fileEntry.fullPath + ": " + this.result);
           };
           reader.readAsText(file);
       }, fail);
   }
   ```

For details, please refer to [File Plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#append-a-file-using-alternative-methods).